# creating a value based on an excel cell, and pushing it into a textbox or label in a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create financial process and system in excel regarding Purchase Order in one of my company entity's. 
I have a created a user form BUT I am trying to have a value of a cell in a worksheet representing on that userform.

I am wanting the PO number to be represented in the user form. that PO number will come from a worksheet with all PO number and just take the last number and +1 to it.
this will then be submitted with all the other information for approval.
I am having an issue with the below code. can anyone help? with ideas and also a explanation into your thinking to workout where I am going wrong.

all advice welcome. I'm very new to VBA.

```
' POnumber variable
Dim PONumber As Long  

' variable for worksheet
Dim PONumberData As Worksheet  

' variable for last POnumber
Dim lastPONumber As Integer    

' variable for last POnumber
Dim PONumtxtBox As TextBox      

' variable for textbox on userform
Dim PONumtxtBox As TextBox  

' variable for PO integer converted to string
Dim PONumberstring As String    


' set textbox variable to userform Textbox

Set PONumtxtBox = Me.PONumberTxtBox

' work outs the last PO number on the PONumberData worksheet

lastPONumber = PONumberData.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Value

' Take's last PO Number and add 1 to it to create next PO number

PONumber = lastPONumber + 1

' converts integer PO number in cell on PONumberData worksheet to string

PONumberstring = CStr(PONumber)

' should add that number to userform * but isn't *

PONumtxtBox.Text = PONumberstring
```

I'm hoping to have a PO number in the userform

Answer (score 0):

You could create a label box inside your UserForm to hold the "PO Number". In the example below, the code is added to the UserForm directly and ran on initialization. It finds the last number in a column and adds one. This assumes that you have your PO Numbers in order in your sheet, otherwise it would not be very helpful.

The "PONumb" references the named label in the UserForm.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Dim R As Integer

        R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Me.PONumb = .Range("A" & R).Value + 1

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou, that's worked perfectly  all it took was 4 lines of code haha simple really :-) that was hurting my head the amount of different things I tried.  so thankyou